# how to convert a 8 bit gray scale bitmap to 4 bit scale in java?

Tags: java, bitmap

I want to read an gray level image file, for example, lena.bmp, then reduce the gray level resolution in java, I used `PixelGrabber` to get the pixels data of this image, how to convert this 8 bit gray scale bitmap to 4 bit?
Thanks!

Comment: You could have a look at http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/?p=329, it may give you some ideas

Comment: @MadProgrammer it just show how to convert a RGB to gray scale, but how to convert a 8 bit bitmp to 4 bit?

Comment: wasn't sure, just thought it might give some ideas, never mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does reduce the number of bits to 4:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
    int w = in.getWidth(), h = in.getHeight();
    int[] bits = { 4 };
    ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
    int dt = DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE;
    ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel
        (cs, bits, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, dt);
    WritableRaster wr = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
    BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(cm, wr, false, null);
    Graphics2D g = out.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(out, "png", new File(args[1]));
}
```

The resulting file will look too dark on all viewer applications I've tried so far. But if you're only interested in the bits, then perhaps operating on the `wr` raster after the above transformation is good enough for you.

If not, then perhaps you should set up an `IndexedColorModel` containing the 2<sup>4</sup> gray levels you want. You can simply multiply the index by 17 to obtain evenly spaced intensities, from `0x0 * 17 = 0x00` through `0xf * 17 = 0xff`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
    int w = in.getWidth(), h = in.getHeight();
    byte[] v = new byte[1 << 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i)
        v[i] = (byte)(i*17);
    ColorModel cm = new IndexColorModel(4, v.length, v, v, v);
    WritableRaster wr = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
    BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(cm, wr, false, null);
    Graphics2D g = out.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(out, "png", new File(args[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not shure if they can help you here, but maybe you can take a look at [JAI (Java Advanced Imaging)](http://java.net/projects/jai/), [Apache Commons Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/) or [Image4j](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/).

### **Edit:**

**Just tested the Image4J Library:**

Converting 8 Bit -> 4 Bit is very simple:

```
final File inFile = new File("test.bmp");
final File outFile = new File("test2.bmp");

BufferedImage inImage = ImageIO.read(inFile);
BufferedImage outImage = ConvertUtil.convert4(inImage); // Converts to 4 Bit

ImageIO.write(outImage, "bmp", outFile);
```

See [Image4J - ConvertUtil Documentation](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html?net/sf/image4j/util/ConvertUtil.html) for more Informations.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks :)